# Как получить переменные в Spring MVC после JavaScript .Fetch()

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

На фронте работал метод `$.ajax()` и было все хорошо. Переписал на `.fetch()` и контроллер перестал видеть переменные. На фронте отправляю запрос так:

```
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('myVar', 'test');

    fetch('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/page', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
        .then(function(json) {/* some acts*/});
```

Обрабатываю запрос так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ResponseEntity myMethod(
        @RequestParam(value = "myVar") String str
) {
    /*Some acts*/
}
```

в `str` приходит `null`. Куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `@RequestParam` ловит переменные из `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. А FormData `multipart/form-data`. Переписал отправку на фронте:

```
 fetch('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/page', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: `myVar=myVal`
    })
```

и полетело

---

**UPD**
Вариант №2:
Подключаем 2 зависимости

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Создаём бин

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="31457280"/>
</bean>
```

И спокойно читаем нашу FormData через аннотацию `@RequestParam`