# Не получается получить доступ к данным, пришедшим от AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

Привет. Отправляю данные к PHP посредством AJAX:

```
let data = {
    id: id,
    search_data: {
        props: proposals,
        airports: airports,
        airlines: airlines,
        gates: gates_info
    }
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/search/start.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: data
    },
    dataType: 'json',
})
```

Интересно, что к `id` я могу получить доступ посредством `$_POST['data']['id']`, а вот во время попытки запарсить данные из `search_data` посредством `$_POST['data']['search_data']` я получаю ошибку:

> Notice:  Undefined index: search_data

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` ......... твоё `data` **НЕ** json

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а какое отношение имеет `dataType` к тому, что PHP не может распарсить `data`? `dataType` - это формат, в котором ожидается ответ от сервера.

Comment: к тому, что ты в итоге на серваке делаешь что? json_decode....... что ты передаешь? **НЕ** json

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос результат `print_r( $_POST['data'] )`?

Comment: @Arnial `при чем тут json_decode зачем его здесь вызывать.` - в связи с тем какую он структуру в итоге пытается послать видимо

Comment: Сквозь пелену лет припоминаю, что такой объект можно затолкать в `JSON.stringlify` на клиенте и `json_decode` на сервере. Когда-то что-то похожее делал, но уже давно `Jquery` не пользовал

Comment: @АлексейШиманский jquery пребразует эту структуру в строку `data[id]=id&data[search_data][pros]=proposals&data[search_data][airports]=airports&data[search_data][airlines]=airlines&data[search_data][gates]=gates_info`, которую отправит постом. PHP сам без проблем распарсит в массив, ему не нужен сдесь json_decode.

Comment: А вообще... Шлите всех `fetch`ем. Там `formData` есть и полифил под старые браузеры. Только учтите что он шлет в `multipart/form-data`. Однажды [для меня это стало неожиданностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665507/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-spring-mvc-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-javascript-fetch)